# aggregating an array of objects by attribute

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts, each with two key/value pairs.  I need to combine dicts that share the same value for the first key, by summing the values of their second keys.  For example:

```
[
    {'foo': 34, 'bar': 2}, 
    {'foo': 34, 'bar': 3}, 
    {'foo': 35, 'bar': 1}, 
    {'foo': 35, 'bar': 7}, 
    {'foo': 35, 'bar': 2}
]
```

would come out as:

```
[
    {'foo': 34, 'bar': 5}, 
    {'foo': 35, 'bar': 10}
]
```

I wrote the following function, which works, but seems horribly verbose, and I am almost sure there is a cool pythonic trick that would be cleaner, and more performant.

```
def combine(arr):
    arr_out = []
    if arr:
        arr_out.append({'foo': arr[0]['foo'], 'bar': 0})
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[i]['foo'] == arr_out[-1]['foo']:
                arr_out[-1]['bar'] += arr[i]['bar']
            else:
                arr_out.append({'foo': arr[i]['foo'], 'bar': arr[i]['bar']})
    return arr_out
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: I chose thefourtheye's answer over falsetru's because in my timeit tests, it performed about 30% better on my likely array sizes.  I suspect that the difference might be smaller for much larger arrays, though.  Interestingly, my original code performed between the two, although it is verbose, as I said.

Comment: @domoarrigato I suspect that the time difference is because the inputs to `groupby` should be `sorted`, which is O(lg N). But the dictionary solution in mine is just O(N).

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question, but the input array is already sorted. Thus, in the benchmarked version of falsetru's solution, I was able to remove the call to `sorted`, and the results for your answer were still faster.  I think, rather, the difference is the overhead of the lambda.

Comment: If it's already sorted, you can skip `sorted` call: `[{'foo': key, 'bar': sum(d['bar'] for d in grp)} for key, grp in itertools.groupby(arr, key=key)]`

Comment: @domoarrigato I am sorry, the sorting complexity is O(N lg N) and you can use `cProfile` to profile the code.

Comment: Hi @falsetru - that's actually exactly what I did for the benchmarks, and what the results reflect.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Group the `bar` values based on the `foo` value and add them.

   ```
   >>> grouper = {}
   >>> for d in data:
   ...     grouper[d["foo"]] = grouper.get(d["foo"], 0) + d["bar"]
   ... 
   >>> grouper
   {34: 5, 35: 10}
   ```
2. Then reconstruct the list of dicts with list comprehension, like this

   ```
   >>> [{"foo": item, "bar": grouper[item]} for item in grouper]
   [{'foo': 34, 'bar': 5}, {'foo': 35, 'bar': 10}]
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> arr = [
...     {'foo': 34, 'bar': 2},
...     {'foo': 34, 'bar': 3},
...     {'foo': 35, 'bar': 1},
...     {'foo': 35, 'bar': 7},
...     {'foo': 35, 'bar': 2}
... ]
>>> import itertools
>>> key = lambda d: d['foo']
>>> [{'foo': key, 'bar': sum(d['bar'] for d in grp)}
...  for key, grp in itertools.groupby(sorted(arr, key=key), key=key)]
[{'foo': 34, 'bar': 5}, {'foo': 35, 'bar': 10}]
```

If the list is already sorted, you can omit `sorted` call:

```
>>> [{'foo': key, 'bar': sum(d['bar'] for d in grp)}
...  for key, grp in itertools.groupby(arr, key=key)]
[{'foo': 34, 'bar': 5}, {'foo': 35, 'bar': 10}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `collections.defaultdict`:

```
def combine(arr):
    c = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for i in arr:
        c[i['foo']] += i['bar']
    # c == {34: 5, 35: 10}

    return [{'foo': k, 'bar': c[k]} for k in sorted(c)]
```

The dictionary `c` is a defaultdict, with the value of 'foo' as the key, and value of 'bar' as the value.